# AS400 - iBM Batch job issue

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am very new and have very minimal knowledge of the AS400 legacy system. Currently, we have AS400 > QBATCH job running every 600 seconds suddenly since last week job stopped picking the files from one the shared location and process it and move it Archive location. I have no idea why this job stopped processing those files from that location. Apparently job is running and processing the batch files from other locations. Any idea where to start and check the logs? Is there a command to restart one of the QBATCH jobs which might help?

Comment: You are going to have to get a lot more information to figure this out.  Are there multiple jobs running in batch and maybe each one is processing a single location.  You can find what a batch job initial command was by putting a 5 next to it and then taking option 10 to view the job log (unless it has wrapped).  Best bet is trying to find the jobs processing the locations that are working and learn more about the command being run and maybe find source of the program.  That might lead you to figuring out why one location isn't working properly.

Comment: This really isn't a programming question..

Comment: Scott, how can we see the source of the program which is running?

Comment: DSPPGM will tell where it was compiled from.  Depending on compile options STRDBG might show it too.